# Parsing text in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

i have this text

```
hello world@helloworld@/dev/zero@inout/helloworld.out
hello world with warnings@warnings@/dev/zero@inout/helloworld.out
echo test@myecho@inout/echo.in@inout/echo.out
echo failtest@myecho@inout/echo.in@inout/helloworld.out
memleaks pass@memleaks@inout/memleaks.6.in@inout/memleaks.6.out
memleaks fail@memleaks@inout/memleaks.11.in@inout/memleaks.11.out
```

i want to run a bash loop that in each run i will read one line and will get 4 vars
each untill the @ (without the @)
and to know what line number i am
i got so far

```
(( index=0 ))
for read line
do
    (( index+=1 ))
    var1=
    var2=
    var3=
    var4=
done
```

what i want to get is

```
var1=hello world
var2=helloworld
var3=/dev/zero
var4=inout/helloworld.out
```

and is there a way to do it in 1 line?

Comment: can you edit to show your expected output in var1, var2 etc

Comment: yes your are right, i added it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash (obviously) has file reading and token splitting build in. To split on a custom separator, set `IFS` to a suitable value.

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=@
while read -r var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    : stuff
done <file
```

You need `oldIFS` if anything else in your script depends on the regular whitespace-solitting behavior. A common arrangement is to put the splitting in a function with a `local` value for `IFS`.

The `-r` option to `read` specifies sane behavior and should be default, but can't be for legacy reasons. The behavior without this option makes sense if you are parsing actual shell code, but not generally.

Comment: Why do you need `oldIFS`? What's wrong with `while IFS=@ read -r ...`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in `awk` with the `-F` flag, which specifies a field separator (equivalent to `$IFS`).

For example, to dump the fields in each line:

```
while read line ; do
  echo $line | awk -F '@' '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'
done
```